# Node.js + Phaser MMO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phaser-framework, mmo

I am currently building a simple MMO game for users to chat, play games and simple things like that.

I have built the server using node.js and socket.io and the client using Phaser.js but I am concerned (based on someone telling me before that my code was not good/structured well in past projects) that this project will become tangled in a big blob of mess.

I am looking for some advice or some helpful links on how I should set up my server structure for the best scalability so in the future I can add more features without the hassle of searching for ages to find that one piece of that that may or may not mess up the whole system

Any advice would be very appreciated, I'm sorry if it is a broad question I am not experience in this field.

Comment: I suggest going over to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. They would be best equipped to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into building it with ExpressJS? It's an MVC structure. I use a Node.js with ExpressJS localhost for my Phaser development. I know the potential for building an MMO with that framework is there.